# A sigma field question

Tags: sigma-algebra

This is real basic, but a question that is annoying me:

$\Omega = \left \{ 1,2,3 \right \}$

$T = \left \{  \emptyset  , \Omega , \left \{ 1,2 \right \}, \left \{ 2,3 \right \}, \left \{ 1,3 \right \}\right \}$

Is $T$ a sigma-field?

Apparently the answer is no because $\left \{ 2,3 \right \}^{c} = \{1\}$ and $\{1\}\notin T$.

**My question is**: isn't $1 \in \Omega$ and therefore $1 \in T$ and $T$ is a sigma-field?

Does each specific set need its own specific complement?

Comment: I think you are confusing an element of $\Omega$, e.g. $1 \in \Omega$, and a set with one element $\{1\}$

Comment: Also I think you meant to write $$T = \{\emptyset, \Omega, \{1,2\}, \{2,3\}, \{1,3\} \}$$ and finally, shouldn't you ask it at math stack?

Comment: To supplement the comments by @ŁukaszGrad, I have fixed up the answer you quote (which is correct and therefore needs to be correctly stated) but I have left your question intact.

Comment: @ŁukaszGrad This is perfectly on-topic here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why is the complement of $\left\{1,2\right\}$ with respect to $\left\{1,2,3\right\}$ equal to $\left\{1\right\}$? It should be equal to $\left\{3\right\}$, which is not in $T$ either. Hence $T$ cannot be a sigma field.

Yes, the complement of each set in $T$ needs to be in $T$ for $T$ to be considered a sigma field. Of course, this condition alone is not sufficient; you need the countable unions too.

Answer (score 2):

A $\sigma$-algebra that consists of a *finite* number of events (subsets of $\Omega$) must have exactly $2^m$ events for some $m \geq 1$. If 
$|\Omega| = n$, then we also have that $m \leq n$. So, since your purported
$\sigma$-algebra has $5$ events in it, it cannot be a $\sigma$-algebra.

Note that this test does not work the other way: the collection $ \left \{  \emptyset,  \Omega, \left \{ 1,2 \right \}, \left \{ 2,3 \right \} \right \}$ of subsets of $\{1,2,3\}$ has $4 = 2^2$ members but it is not a $\sigma$-algebra. On the other hand, 
$ \left \{ \emptyset, \Omega, \left \{ 1,2 \right \}, \left \{ 3 \right \} \right \}$ also consists of $4$ subsets but *is* a $\sigma$-algebra. That is, having $2^m$
members is a *necessary* condition but *not a sufficient condition*
for a collection of subsets of $\Omega$ to constitute a $\sigma$-algebra.